# Display names of APIs in a picker view in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uipickerview

I want to display the names for an array of APIs in a picker view.

Example:
"fox-sports" displayed as FOX Sports on the picker view.

I'm currently placing an array of the API names.

```
var pickerData = ["SELECT A SOURCE", "espn", "nfl-news", "fox-sports", "bbc-
sport", "the-sport-bible", "sky-sports-news"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use Dictionary to store API names:

```
let channels = [
    "espn": "ESPN",
    "fox-sports": "FOX Sports",
]
let pickerData = ["SELECT A SOURCE"] + channels.values
```

And when you want to use keys: `channels.keys`